# Troubleshoot with setting NSOperation object to a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, nsoperation

I seem to have struck with a simple looking issue which I cannot figure out. As shown in the image, I have a `NSOperation` object which is created and am trying to set it to a `NSMutableDictionary` which sets "null" to the key instead instead of the `NSOperation` object.

[image]

The `keyToOperationDictionary` is created by lazy loading, here is the code:

```
@synthesize keyToOperationDictionary = keyToOperationDictionary_;
-(NSMutableDictionary*)keyToOperationDictionary
{
    if (nil==keyToOperationDictionary_)
    {
        keyToOperationDictionary_ = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return keyToOperationDictionary_;
}
```

I don't know what else is going wrong here. When I print the object in debug console, it shows me the object but the same object is not set to the dictionary.

Any help / suggestions would be of great help!

PS: I forgot to mention earlier that it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. I have no clue why!

Added details:

**`CSStatisticsKey class:`**

**The interface:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CSDateRange.h"
#import "CSStatisticsManager.h"
#import "CSStatisticsManagerDelegateProtocol.h"

@interface CSStatisticsKey : NSObject <NSCopying, NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) CSDateRange *dateRange;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *statisticsDelegatePointer;

// Designated initializer
-(id)initWithDateRange:(CSDateRange*)inDateRange statisticsDelegate:(id<CSStatisticsManagerDelegateProtocol>)inStatisticsDelegate;

@end
```

**The implementation:**

```
@interface CSStatisticsKey()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CSDateRange *dateRange;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *statisticsDelegatePointer;
@end

@implementation CSStatisticsKey

- (id)init
{
    return [self initWithDateRange:nil
                statisticsDelegate:nil];
}

-(id)initWithDateRange:(CSDateRange*)inDateRange statisticsDelegate:(id<CSStatisticsManagerDelegateProtocol>)inStatisticsDelegate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setDateRange:inDateRange];
        [self setStatisticsDelegatePointer:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", inStatisticsDelegate]];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - NSCopying
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self]];
}

#pragma mark - NSCoding
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.dateRange forKey:@"TheDateRange"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.statisticsDelegatePointer forKey:@"TheStatsDelegateValue"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    CSDateRange *dRange =[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"TheDateRange"];
    NSString *dValue = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"TheStatsDelegateValue"];
    CSStatisticsKey *theDelegate = [[CSStatisticsKey alloc] init];
    [theDelegate setStatisticsDelegatePointer:dValue];
    [theDelegate setDateRange:dRange];
    return theDelegate;
}

#pragma mark - Equality
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    BOOL delegatesAreEqual = NO;

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[CSStatisticsKey class]])
    {
        CSStatisticsKey *statsDelegate = (CSStatisticsKey*)object;
        if ([self.dateRange isEqual:statsDelegate.dateRange] && [self.statisticsDelegatePointer isEqual:statsDelegate.statisticsDelegatePointer])
        {
            delegatesAreEqual = YES;
        }
    }
    return delegatesAreEqual;
}

#pragma mark - Description
-(NSString*)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@-%@", self.statisticsDelegatePointer, self.dateRange.fromDate, self.dateRange.toDate];
}
@end
```

Comment: 1. Are you compiling this in debug configuration?
2. Does `CSStatisticsKey` conform to `NSCoding` and is immutable?

Comment: Yes am compiling in debug config, but I think this should not make a difference. For testing purpose I replaced setting with operation object and tried to set @"Hi" which always works, as expected, but the operation object doesn't. CSStatisticsKey class conforms to both NSCodying and NSCopying protocol. I have posted the class' code above, please check.

Comment: Unrelated, but `CSStatisticsKey *theDelegate = [[CSStatisticsKey alloc] init];` doesn't need to be done. The object has already been allocated. Just call `[self set...]` methods and return `self` object.

Comment: You are right in a way that I should be using a 'self' pointer. But the object is not created at the time when -initWithCoder is called, instead the purpose of -initWithCoder method is to create an object and return it back to the caller.

Comment: @Mar0ux - I was wrong in my understanding about 'purpose of -initWithCoder method is to create an object'. Thanks for pointing it out and for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be some problem with the lldb debugger. At the same breakpoint location shown above, when I run the following commands, I get the following output:

```
(lldb) po self.keyToOperationDictionary
$1 = 0x144647b0 {
    "a4779e0 2013-07-01 00:00:00 +0000-2013-07-31 00:00:00 +0000" = (null);
    "a4779e0 0003-11-01 00:00:00 +0000-0003-11-30 00:00:00 +0000" = "<CSStatisticsOperation: 0x14464d20>";
}
(lldb) po theKey
$2 = 0x0a5270a0 a4779e0 2013-07-01 00:00:00 +0000-2013-07-31 00:00:00 +0000
(lldb) po [self.keyToOperationDictionary objectForKey:theKey]
$3 = 0x14168c30 <CSStatisticsOperation: 0x14168c30>
(lldb)
```

Pretty clear that there is something wrong with the debugger and hence the dictionary is not printing the operation object.